# Style.visibility doesn't hide the elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so im sorry for "mistakes".

Problem:
I have to do the frontend for a CMS System. Therefore I want menu-bars which can expand / contract in order to give other options and tools space.
The contracting is working fine. And yes, I know that its not expanding back. But thats not my problem currently. A simple toggle can fix that :)

Here is the interesting part of the html. I dont include CSS since I dont think its necessary here. Im also not adding the html and body tags since I think that you guys will spot the mistake anyways :)

```
    <container id="main">
      <div class="main-part left" id="menu-left">
        <button class="navigation-toggle bgcontain" onClick="lefttoggle()"></button>
        <ul>
          <li><div class="menuicon baseicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">base</p></li>
          <li><div class="menuicon cmsicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">cms</p></li>
          <li><div class="menuicon shopicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">shop</p></li>
          <li><div class="menuicon mamicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">mam</p></li>
          <li><div class="menuicon w2picon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">w2p</p></li>
          <li><div class="menuicon workicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">workflow</p></li>
          <li><div class="menuicon mailicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer" id="contract"></div><p id="contract">mail</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main-part center">
        <button class="navigation-toggle bgcontain"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="main-part right">

      </div>
    </container>

    <script>

      function lefttoggle() {
        //document.getElementById('menu-left').style.width = '60px';
        //document.getElementById('menu-left').style.minWidth = '60px';
        document.getElementById('contract').style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
</script>
```

I want the divs and p's with the ID "contract" to get invisible since I want to reduce the menu bar to just the icons.

Thanks to all of you :)

Comment: ID values must be unique. (What good is an identifier if it doesn't identify?) `getElementById` therefore only returns one element. You should be using  a class.

Comment: Off topic: You seem to be using markup to create space in your layout. This can almost certainly be done with CSS.

Comment: Thanks dude, makes sense :D

Im using jscript because I want to learn how it works. I know how to use scss, sass, css and less, but I never really touched jscript so far :)

Comment: Jscript isn't a factor here (assuming you're using the term correctly--it isn't slang for JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elments with same id on a page. So change them to class and use `getElementsByClassName` function

```html
<script>
function lefttoggle() {

    console.log("here")
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('contract')
 for (var i=0; i< elems.length; i++) {
elems[i].parentElement.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}

  }
  </script>


<container id="main">
  <div class="main-part left" id="menu-left">
    <button class="navigation-toggle bgcontain" onclick="lefttoggle()">T</button>
    <ul>
      <li><div class="menuicon baseicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">base</p></li>
      <li><div class="menuicon cmsicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">cms</p></li>
      <li><div class="menuicon shopicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">shop</p></li>
      <li><div class="menuicon mamicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">mam</p></li>
      <li><div class="menuicon w2picon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">w2p</p></li>
      <li><div class="menuicon workicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">workflow</p></li>
      <li><div class="menuicon mailicon bgcontain"></div><div class="ul-vspacer contract"></div><p id="contract">mail</p></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-part center">
    <button class="navigation-toggle bgcontain"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="main-part right">

  </div>
</container>
```

Comment: you can foreach the result of getElementsByClassName, i.e. getElementsByClassName().forEach(function(elem) { elem.style... })

Comment: oh, then querySelectorAll is more convenient, my fiddle worked with foreach

Comment: I just checked that the querySelectorAll  returns a A NodeList object,so the forEach can work on it. But getElementsByClassName  returns  an HTMLCollection so the forEach doesnt work on it

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.getElementById` or you will only return one item.  But, since you're after the ID and you can only have a single element with any given ID you should give all those elements a class and use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: I exchanged getElementById with querySelectorAll, but its still not working :/
Maybe I'm to stupid since I haven't really touched jscript till today.
But thanks for your answer anyways :)

Comment: Use a class and `document.getElementsByClassName`.  IDs need to be unique

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` won't work since it returns only one DOM element, I haven't tried this with a document with multiple elements with the same ID but presumably it will return the first element. You can use `querySelectorAll` and use the element ID with # prefix to make your code work -- i.e #contract, or more conveniently add contract to the class attribute of the elements and use `getElementByClassName`. Both functions return an array of DOM elements so chaining style.visibility directly won't work. You have to loop through the results and set the style inside the loop. Here is a fiddle that could help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/yan0zvb7/